# Unknown column name 'table.column' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql, database, node.js, inner-join

I'm struggling with a weird issue with MySQL while using an inner join (although I'm not sure if that's the cause of it). My issue occurs when I try to select a column from a particular table (the column is ambiguous). I'm getting a friendly little error telling me that the column doesn't exist.  (Unknown column 'items.id' in 'field list')

Anyway, here's my query:

```
SELECT `items`.`id`, `chemical_name`, `full_name`, `amount`, `smiles`, `inchi`, `inchikey`, `average_mass`, `molecular_weight`, `monoisotopic_mass`, `nominal_mass` FROM `items` A INNER JOIN `chemicals` B ON A.csid = B.csid WHERE `owner` = '2'
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this some weird MySQL bug?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use the alias `A` for your table `items`.

use `A.id` in your select instead of `items.Id` and you should be fine

Comment: Ah that's got it, thanks :) I can't accept your answer for another 7 minutes, but I will when I can